# Java crash when database is empty

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I am using the SQLite JDBC driver to access a database, for some reason the application terminates if there are no rows in the database with little explanation as to why it happened.

If the database is not empty it works perfectly fine;

This is where the termination occurs:

```
public static CustomFillTable Select(String table, String[] column, Object operand) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {  
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

            query.append("select ");

            for(int i = 0; i < column.length; i++)
            {
                query.append(column[i]);

                if(i < column.length -1)
                {
                    query.append(",");
                }
            }

            query.append(" from ");
            query.append(table);

            //Verify usage of where clause
            if(operand != null)
            {
                query.append(" where ");
                query.append(operand);
            }

            //Termination occurs here
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_connectionString);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            connection.commit();
            CustomFillTable model = new CustomFillTable(rs);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("id = " + rs.getString("id"));
                System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
            }

            return model;
        }
```

The application closes at the DriverManager.getConnection line, something I don't find to be related to whether the database is populated or not.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? I've posted the log dump information [here](http://pastebin.com/BTuethVz).

**Edit:**

Connection String -

**"jdbc:sqlite:D:\Documents\Uni\Semester 2\Languages, Platforms and Tools\Assignment\Java\SQLiteAssignment\mydatabasefile.db"**

Comment: Could you post what your _connectionString is?

Comment: ouch. that looks like it could be a bug in the jdbc driver.

Comment: I'm sure it worked before, now nothing =/

Comment: yeah this looks like a bug in the driver. What were you doing before? Did you upgrade something perhaps the driver?

Comment: Noting that I am aware of, I did try a different driver yesterday but decided against it. I reimplemented a backup from weeks ago and it does the same thing, I don't understand what's happened at all really.

Comment: What do people recommend? Rewrite my application to use a new Driver?

Comment: Verify that an errant driver didn't sneak into one of the `java.ext.dirs`.

Comment: Perhaps your db file got corrupted? Delete the file and create a new one?

Comment: @Karthik That wouldn't explain why it can be read when there are records but no if it's empty. Tried anyway and didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I would check the SQLite jdbc driver page and see if you can find a link to their bug tracking software. Maybe someone has filed a bug for something similar to this that can help you out?

Comment: I'm using the Xerial driver - http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial, although I don't need the XML it seems easy to use. I have tried the one by Zentus - http://www.zentus.com/ but the syntax confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the vendors website it seems it is something that has been addressed in a later build. I ended up changing driver anyway but I thought this might be of some use to people.